# Changing the value of a form input field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i change the value of this input field using jquery?

```
<input type="hidden" name="emailaddress" value="admin@admin.com">
```

Comment: google is your friend :) see [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [manipulating elements](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('input:hidden[name=emailaddress]').val('something');
```

Here,

`input:hidden` point to hidden input

`[name=emailaddress]` check for `name` attribute.

so totally

`$('input:hidden[name=emailaddress]')` select the input which is hidden and with `name` attribute `emailaddress`.

`.val()` used to set/get value to input field. With parameter it acts as a setter and getter without it.

Comment: this helped. short, small and minimal

Comment: any recommended resources? books? articles?

Comment: @Manishearth I've explaine my code, now you should do your work

Answer (score 1):

you need to give the input an id and then reference the id and change it. below is what i have used to change the value of a radio button. this uses JS

```
     document.getElementById('ID').value = somevalue;
```

Along with

```
    <input type="hidden" name="emailaddress" id ='ID'value="admin@admin.com">
```